# Elevation on button causing problems with view

Tags: android, button, view

[image]I am trying to make the WHOLE of the blue button (As seen on the picture) on the top of the view. However, it is only showing the button half. I have sussed out it's something to do with the elevation, however I'm not sure what as I have tried the possibilities I can think of.

My XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:baselineAligned="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/contentView"
            android:layout_width="341dp"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_container"
            android:elevation="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/contentView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/background"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emailAddress"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: As a reposnse to whoever just deleted their comment, How would I then go about positioning it after taking it out of the RelativeLayout?

Comment: check answer ...

Answer (score 0):

take button out of relative layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#FFFFFF"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:baselineAligned="false">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <View
            android:id="@+id/contentView"
            android:layout_width="341dp"
            android:layout_height="340dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_container"
            android:elevation="8dp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/contentView"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/background"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="41dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/emailAddress"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />




    </RelativeLayout>
    <Button <----- change 
        android:id="@+id/loginButton"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_button"
        android:elevation="8dp"
        android:text="LOGIN"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</LinearLayout>
```

problem is not button elevations is your View hiding button

```
 <View
        android:id="@+id/contentView"
        android:layout_width="341dp"
        android:layout_height="340dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:background="@drawable/login_container"
        android:elevation="8dp" />
```

this part is hiding your button you can check it in xml
I would suggest using Scrol view as well because this UI wont work on small screen devices  as many heights are hard coded

Comment: This positions the button under the Relative Layout. When I then go to drag and drop it into place, it moves itself back INTO the ReleativeLayout

Comment: chagne relative layouts hide to wrap content

Comment: Doing that sort of works, however it would need to be something like wrap_content - 25 as it is just under the white box

Comment: problem is your <View /> they have hard coded heights . UI will look different on different screens. Try using weights with linear layout

Answer (score 0):

My apologies to be blunt, but your layout is not well designed.
You have linearLayout with nested RelativeLayout and the parent is now not serving a purpose.

Use the root that you intend to use. If it is relative layout, then use that. If you plan to stack more content below or above the relative layout then it makes sense, but your sample it doesn't serve a purpose.

Now as to your problem. You are using a relative layout and just stacking views on views on views. First, your parent should have the container background, you should not have a view nested in the parent RelativeLayout that has the background intended to be the parent's background.

So I would move your container background to the RelativeLayout and remove the view altogether as your hard coded height width on that could be playing a role as well.

So before we hunt down any goofy behaviors, let's get the design done properly first than we can see what we are looking for if it is still acting up.

Try something like this instead:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:background="#FFFFFF"
              android:gravity="center"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:baselineAligned="false">

    <View
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="35dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="35dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/login_container">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:textSize="24sp" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/emailAddress"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Email address"
            android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/password"
            android:layout_width="270dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Password"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/loginButton"
            android:layout_width="200dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_marginBottom="45dp"
            android:background="@drawable/login_button"
            android:elevation="8dp"
            android:text="LOGIN"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />


    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't test it as i don't have your code, and you will have to adjust the margins. Also, change your preview to the 3.7 so you can see that your design may need some adjusting for small devices. Lastly, you could always use a cardview for this if desired.